# Switch from Countdown to Countup

Tags: swift, countdown

stackoverflow is my last chance. I hope you can help me. I have a countdown in my app which is set to 2 hours and 30 minutes. When it hits 0 it starts to count up to 30 minutes. After the 30 minutes are over, the countdown is back at 2:30. Everything is working fine except the part when the timer is switching from the countdown part to the countup part. Here is the problem: The timer is going negative when hitting zero.

```
 @objc func startTimer() {
    print("Countdown : \(totalTime)")
    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

 @objc func updateTime() {
    if (totalTime > 10800) {
        totalTime = totalTime - 10800
    }


    totalTime -= 1
    var time = totalTime


    //When in session...
    if (time > 9000) {

        //Calculate CountUP
        time = 10800 - time

        //if session has started
        if(isSessionActive == false) {
            isSessionActive = true
            lastFiveMinutes = false
            self.setSessionStarted()
        }
    } else {
        //If session has ended...
        if(isSessionActive == true) {
            isSessionActive = false
            lastFiveMinutes = false
            self.setSessionEnded()
        }
        //If last 5 minutes have started
        if(time < 300 && lastFiveMinutes == false) {
            lastFiveMinutes = true
            self.setLastFiveMinutes()
        }
    }
    countdownLabel.text = "\(timeFormatted(time))"

    //update Participant Count every x second, ONLY if in last 5 Minutes or Session is active
    if (lastFiveMinutes == true || isSessionActive == true) {
        if (totalTime % 5 == 0) {
            setParticipants(n: httpController.getPar())
        }
    } else {
        setParticipants(n: "...")
    }

}
```

The part "var time = totalTime" is not necessary, i know.

In Android the code is exactly the same except the -=1 part, but it is working.

*** Update ***

Inital Value of totalTime: 
     @objc var totalTime = 0

And here is the next part where it gets a real value.

```
@objc func initCountdown() {
    var currentSec = 0.0
    // Get Current Time from Server
    serverTimeReturn { (getResDate) -> Void in
        let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
        dFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
        dFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")! as TimeZone
        let dateGet = dFormatter.string(from: getResDate! as Date)
        currentSec = Double((getResDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!)

        print("Formatted Hour : \(dateGet)")

        let todaySec = Int(currentSec) % 86400
        print("Today Sec Hour : \(todaySec)")
        let countDownSec = 10800 - todaySec % 10800

        // Check status to init
        if(countDownSec > 9000) {
            self.isSessionActive = true
            self.setSessionStarted()
        } else {
            self.setSessionEnded()
        }
        if(countDownSec < 300) {
            self.setLastFiveMinutes()
            self.lastFiveMinutes = true
        }
        self.totalTime = countDownSec
    }
    print("Formatted Hour : \(totalTime)")
    startTimer()
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `totalTime`?

Comment: @Carpsen90 see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code where you count upwards so I  am not surprised it isn't working. I would introduce a boolean property `isCountingDown` to keep track of how to handle the timer and then have two separate methods for up and down

```
var isCountingDown: boolean

@objc func initCountdown() {
    //existing code

   isCountingDown = true
   startTimer()
}

@objc func updateTime() {
    if isCountingDown {
        doCountDown()
    } else {
        doCountUp()
    }
}
```

And then in `doCountDown()` and `doCountUp()` I would check against time is 0 or 30 and update `isCountingDown` accordingly

```
func doCountDown {
   if (totalTime > 10800) {
       totalTime = totalTime - 10800
   }

   totalTime -= 1
   if totalTime == 0 {
       isCountingDown = false
       //Maybe return here?
   }
   var time = totalTime
   //rest of code
}

func doCountUp() {
    totalTime += 1

    if totalTime == 30 {
        isCountingDown = true
       //Maybe return here?
   }
   //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this one out. The freelancer said that the count up part is done by offset i think. Thats the part: "Calculate CountUP /  time = 10800 - time" Actually the count up part works very well when i open the app during the 30 minutes. The error only comes up when i watch the countdown counting down to 0 and then going zero and negativ. But when i close the app and restart, the count up part works perfectly.